# Single instance of full CKEditor v4 is shown with two toolbars

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have created a page with full build CKEditor v4. I have one instance on page, but it has two toll bars??? It is classic instance (no in-line) and 1 (custom toolbar) in a static on page, but second toolbar showing only when i focused on text, I put an attachments of a screenshot bottom and my build-config.js and config on page. Have any ideas why?

build-config.js:

```js
var CKBUILDER_CONFIG = {
 skin: 'moono-lisa',
 preset: 'full',
 ignore: [
  '.DS_Store',
  '.bender',
  '.editorconfig',
  '.gitattributes',
  '.gitignore',
  '.idea',
  '.jscsrc',
  '.jshintignore',
  '.jshintrc',
  '.mailmap',
  '.npm',
  '.travis.yml',
  'bender-err.log',
  'bender-out.log',
  'bender.ci.js',
  'bender.js',
  'dev',
  'gruntfile.js',
  'less',
  'node_modules',
  'package.json',
  'tests'
 ],
 plugins : {
  'a11yhelp' : 1,
  'about' : 1,
  'allowsave' : 1,
  'base64image' : 1,
  'basicstyles' : 1,
  'bidi' : 1,
  'blockquote' : 1,
  'colorbutton' : 1,
  'colordialog' : 1,
  'contextmenu' : 1,
  'dialogadvtab' : 1,
  'divarea' : 1,
  'enterkey' : 1,
  'entities' : 1,
  'filebrowser' : 1,
  'find' : 1,
  'floatingspace' : 1,
  'font' : 1,
  'format' : 1,
  'forms' : 1,
  'horizontalrule' : 1,
  'htmlwriter' : 1,
  'indentblock' : 1,
  'indentlist' : 1,
  'justify' : 1,
  'link' : 1,
  'list' : 1,
  'liststyle' : 1,
  'lite' : 1,
  'loremipsum' : 1,
  'magicline' : 1,
  'maximize' : 1,
  'pagebreak' : 1,
  'pastefromword' : 1,
  'pastetext' : 1,
  'removeformat' : 1,
  'resize' : 1,
  'selectall' : 1,
  'showborders' : 1,
  'showprotected' : 1,
  'specialchar' : 1,
  'stylescombo' : 1,
  'tab' : 1,
  'tableresize' : 1,
  'tableresizerowandcolumn' : 1,
  'tableselection' : 1,
  'tabletools' : 1,
  'texzilla' : 1,
  'undo' : 1,
  'uploadimage' : 1,
  'wordcount' : 1,
  'zoom' : 1
 },
 languages : {
  'en' : 1
 }
};
```

config on page:

```js
CKEDITOR.replace(editorId, {
            on: {
                instanceReady: function (ev) {
                    console.log('CKE4 Editor Was Initialized', editorId);

                    var writer = ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer;
                    writer.indentationChars = '    ';

                    var dtd = CKEDITOR.dtd;
                    for (var e in CKEDITOR.tools.extend({}, dtd.$block, dtd.$listItem, dtd.$tableContent)) {
                        ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules(e, {
                            indent: false,
                            breakBeforeOpen: false,
                            breakAfterOpen: false,
                            breakBeforeClose: false,
                            breakAfterClose: false
                        });
                    }

                    for (var e in CKEDITOR.tools.extend({}, dtd.$list, dtd.$listItem, dtd.$tableContent)) {
                        ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules(e, {
                            indent: true,
                        });
                    }

                    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules('table',
                    {
                        indent: true
                    });

                    ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules('form',
                    {
                        indent: true
                    });
                }
                ,
                fileUploadResponse: function (evt) {
                    // Prevent the default response handler.
                    evt.stop();

                    // Get XHR and response.
                    var data = evt.data,
                        xhr = data.fileLoader.xhr,
                        response = xhr.responseText.split('|');
                    var json = JSON.parse(evt.data.fileLoader.xhr.responseText);

                    if (json.message != undefined) {
                        // An error occurred during upload.
                        data.message = json.message;
                        evt.cancel();
                    } else {
                        data.url = json.url;//response[0];
                    }
                    //var url = JSON.parse(evt.data.fileLoader.xhr.responseText).url;
                    CKEDITOR.instances[editorId].insertHtml('<img alt="' + json.fileName + '" data-cke-saved-src="' + json.url + '" src="' + json.url + '">');
                }
            },
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: ImageUploadUrl,
            filebrowserUploadMethod: 'form',
            toolbarLocation: 'top',
            disableNativeSpellChecker: true,
            title: false,
            allowedContent: true,
            pasteFromWordCleanupFile: WordCleanupFile,
            baseFloatZIndex: 15000,
            height: 500,
            wight: 1500,
            wordcount: {
                showCharCount: true,
                showWordCount: true,
                countSpacesAsChars: true,
                countHTML: true,
                countLineBreaks: true,
                wordLimit: 'unlimited'
            }
            ,
            toolbar: [
          { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize'] },
                { name: 'document', items: ['Preview', 'Print'] },
          //{ name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord' ] },
                { name: 'clipboard', items: ['Cut', 'Copy', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
          { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
          { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript'] },
          { name: 'basicstyles', items: ['RemoveFormat'] },
          { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
          { name: 'paragraph', items: ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'] },
          { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
          { name: 'paragraph', items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'bidiltr', 'bidirtl'] },
          { name: 'insert', items: ['base64image', 'Image', 'Table'] },
                { name: 'uploadimage', items: ['uploadimage'] },
          { name: 'insert', items: ['HorizontalRule', 'PageBreak', 'IPCom'] },
                { name: 'texzilla', items: ['texzilla'] },
          { name: 'editing', items: ['SelectAll', '-', 'Scayt'] },
                { name: 'zoom', items: ['Zoom'] },
                { name: 'editing', items: ['Find', 'Replace', ] },
                { name: 'tools', items: ['ShowBlocks'] },
                { name: 'lite', items: ['lite-acceptall', 'lite-rejectall', 'lite-acceptone', 'lite-rejectone'] }
            ]
        });
```

This is how it currently looks like:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Only in Google Chrome!